# The conditions in the definition of Poisson process (and a Lévy process generalization)

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Last week, George Lowther provided a rather sophisticated counter-example of a continuous process $\{W(t):t \geq 0\}$ with $W(0)=0$ and $W(t)-W(s) \sim {\rm N}(0,t-s)$ for all $0 \leq s < t$, yet not a Brownian motion; see [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43015/the-conditions-in-the-definition-of-brownian-motion). 
Apparently, his approach relied heavily on special properties of BM.

Now, what about the analogue for a Poisson process: Can you find an example of a càdlàg (right-continuous with left limits) process $\{X(t):t \geq 0\}$ with $X(0)=0$ and $X(t)-X(s) \sim {\rm Poi}(t-s)$ for all $0 \leq s < t$, yet not being a Poisson process?

Bonus question: If the last question turns out to be too easy to answer (etc.), then what about the general Lévy process case? That is, given a Lévy process $X$ (defined below) with law $\mu_t$ at time $t>0$, does there exist a càdlàg process $\tilde X$ with $\tilde X(0) = 0$ and $\tilde X(t)-\tilde X(s) \sim \mu_{t-s}$  for all $0 \leq s < t$, which is yet not identical in law to $X$ (hence not a  Lévy process)? [Here, assume that $X$ is non-deterministic, equivalently, $\mu_t$ is not a $\delta$-distribution.]

Definition: A stochastic process $X=\{X(t):t \geq 0\}$ is a *Lévy process* (say, real-valued) if the following conditions are satisfied: (1) $X(0)=0$ a.s.; (2) $X$ has independent increments; (3) $X$ has stationary increments; (4) $X$ is stochastically continuous; (5) Almost surely, the function $t \mapsto X(t)$ is right-continuous (for $t \geq 0$) and has left limits (for $t>0$). [In fact, condition (4) is implied by (1), (3), and (5).]

PS: you are still welcome to try and find a simpler counter-example for the Brownian motion case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot define a Lévy process by the individual distributions of its increments, except in the trivial case of a deterministic process *X*<sub>*t*</sub> − *X*<sub>0</sub> = *bt* with constant *b*. In fact, you can't identify it by the n-dimensional marginals for any n.

> 1) Let *X* be a nondeterministic Lévy process with *X*<sub>0</sub> = 0 and *n* be any positive integer. Then, there is a cadlag process *Y* with a different distribution to *X*, but such that (*Y*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*Y*<sub>*t*<sub>2</sub></sub>,…,*Y*<sub>*t*<sub>*n*</sub></sub>) has the same distribution as (*X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>2</sub></sub>,…,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>n</sub></sub>) for all times *t*<sub>1</sub>,*t*<sub>2</sub>,…,*t*<sub>*n*</sub>.

Taking *n* = 2 will give a process whose increments have the same distribution as for *X*.

The idea (as in my answer to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43015/the-conditions-in-the-definition-of-brownian-motion)) is to reduce it to the finite-time case. So, fix a set of times 0 = *t*<sub>0</sub> < *t*<sub>1</sub> < *t*<sub>2</sub> < … < *t*<sub>*m*</sub> for some *m* > 1.
We can look at the distribution of *X* conditioned on the ℝ<sup>*m*</sup>-valued random variable *U* ≡ (*X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>2</sub></sub>,…,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*m*</sub></sub>). By the Markov property, it will consist of a set of independent processes on the intervals [*t*<sub>*k*−1</sub>,*t*<sub>*k*</sub>] and [*t*<sub>*m*</sub>,∞), where the distribution of {*X*<sub>*t*</sub> }<sub>*t* ∈[*t*<sub>*k*−1</sub>,*t*<sub>*k*</sub>]</sub> only depends on (*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*−1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*</sub></sub>) and the distribution of {*X*<sub>*t*</sub> }<sub>*t* ∈[*t*<sub>*m*</sub>,∞)</sub> only depends on *X*<sub>*t*<sub>*m*</sub></sub>. By the [disintegration theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem), the process *X* can be built by first constructing the random variable *U*, then constructing *X* to have the correct probabilities conditional on *U*. Doing this, the distribution of *X* at any one time only depends on the values of at most two elements of *U* (corresponding to *X*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*−1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*</sub></sub>). The distribution of *X* at any set of *n* times depends on the values of at most 2*n* values of *U*.

Choosing *m* > 2*n*, the idea is to replace *U* by a differently distributed ℝ<sup>*m*</sup>-valued random variable for which any 2*n* elements still have the same distribution as for *U*. We can apply a small bump to the distribution of *U* in such a way that the *m* − 1 dimensional marginals are unchanged. To do this, we can use the following.

> 2) Let *U* be an ℝ<sup>*m*</sup>-valued random variable with probability measure μ. Suppose that there exist (non-trival) measures μ<sub>1</sub>,μ<sub>2</sub>,…,μ<sub>*m*</sub> on the reals such that μ<sub>1</sub>(*A*<sub>1</sub>)μ<sub>2</sub>(*A*<sub>2</sub>)…μ<sub>*m*</sub>(*A*<sub>*m*</sub>) ≤ μ(*A*<sub>1</sub>×*A*<sub>2</sub>×…×*A*<sub>*m*</sub>) for all Borel subsets *A*<sub>1</sub>,*A*<sub>2</sub>,…,*A*<sub>*m*</sub> ⊆ ℝ.
>   Then, there is an ℝ<sup>*m*</sup>-valued  random variable *V* with a different distribution to *U*, but with the same *m* − 1 dimensional marginal distributions.

By 'non-trivial' I mean that μ<sub>*k*</sub> is a non-zero measure and does not consist of a single atom.

By changing the distribution of *U* in this way, we construct a new cadlag process with a different distribution to *X*, but with the same *n* dimensional marginals.

Proving (2) is easy enough. As μ<sub>*k*</sub> are non-trivial, there will be measurable functions ƒ<sub>*k*</sub> on the reals, uniformly bounded by 1 and such that μ<sub>*k*</sub>(ƒ<sub>*k*</sub>) = 0 and μ<sub>*k*</sub>(|ƒ<sub>*k*</sub>|) > 0. Replacing μ<sub>*k*</sub> by the signed measure ƒ<sub>*k*</sub>·μ<sub>*k*</sub>, we can assume that μ<sub>*k*</sub>(ℝ) = 0.
Then
$$
\mu_V = \mu + \mu_1\times\mu_2\times\cdots\times\mu_m
$$
is a probability measure different from μ. Choosing *V* with this distribution gives
$$
{\mathbb E}[f(V)]=\mu_V(f)=\mu(f)={\mathbb E}[f(U)]
$$
for any function ƒ: ℝ<sup>*m*</sup> → ℝ<sup>+</sup> independent of one of the dimensions. So, *V* has the same *m* − 1 dimensional marginals as *U*.

To apply (2) to *U* = (*X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>2</sub></sub>,…,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*m*</sub></sub>), consider the following cases.

1. *X* is continuous. In this case, *X* is just a Brownian motion (up to multiplication by a constant and addition of a constant drift). So, *U* is joint-normal with nondegenerate covariance matrix. Its probability density is continuous and strictly positive so, in (2), we can take μ<sub>*k*</sub> to be a multiple of the uniform measure on [0,1].
2. *X* is a Poisson process. In this case, we can take μ<sub>*k*</sub> to be a multiple of the (discrete) uniform distribution on {2*k*,2*k* + 1} and, as *X* can take any increasing nonnegative integer-valued path on the times *t*<sub>*k*</sub>, this satisfies the hypothesis of (2).
3. If *X* is any non-continuous Lévy process, case 2 can be used to change the distribution of its jump times without affecting the *n* dimensional marginals: Let ν be its jump measure, and *A* be a Borel set such that ν(*A*) is finite and nonzero. Then, *X* decomposes as the sum of its jumps in *A* (which occur according to a Poisson process of rate ν(*A*)) and an independent Lévy process. In this way, we can reduce to the case where *X* is a Lévy process whose jumps occur at a finite rate, with arrival times given by a Poisson process.
   In that case, let *N*<sub>*t*</sub> be the Poisson process counting the number of jumps in intervals [0,*t*]. Also, let *Z*<sub>*k*</sub> be the *k*'th jump of *X*. Then, *N* and the *Z*<sub>*k*</sub> are all independent and,
   $$
   X_t=\sum_{k=1}^{N_t}Z_k.
   $$
   As above, the Poisson process *N* can be replaced by a differently distributed cadlag process which has the same *n* dimensional marginals. This will not affect the *n* dimensional marginals of *X* but, as its jump times no longer occur according to a Poisson process, *X* will no longer be a Lévy process.

Comment: It will take me a while to go over such an answer.

Comment: Very elegant solution! [Note the typo before "is a probability measure" (you may wish to add here "different from $\mu$"), where $n$ should be $m$.] 

Comment: @Shai: Thanks. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to this answer, I no longer believe what I initially wrote (still appearing at the bottom of the answer). It seems to me a construction should be possible. It is at least possible in the case of a Binomial point process.

Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N},i\neq 4}$ be independent Bernoulli$(1/2)$ random variables. 
Let $X_4'$ be Bernoulli$(1/2)$ and independent of the $X_i$. Then define $X_4$ as follows:

- $X_4 = 1$ if $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is either $(0,0,1)$ or $(1,1,0)$,
- $X_3 = 0$ if $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is either $(0,1,0)$ or $(1,0,1)$,
- $X_4=X_4'$ otherwise.

Then for all $j \geq 0$, $n \geq 1$, $X_{j+1}+\ldots+X_{j+n}$ has Binomial$(n,1/2)$ distribution but the family $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are not iid.

---

What appears below (where I suggested such a construction was impossible) is false.

---

For a standard Poisson process, this won't be possible. (See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39491/a-point-process-is-characterized-by-its-void-probabilities) and its answer.)

**Edit**: Given the comments perhaps I should provide more detail.

With probability one, for every pair $0 < p < q$, $p,q$ rationals, $X(q)−X(p)$ is a non-negative integer. Since X is cadlag the same property must hold for every real pair $0 < s < t$, i.e. $X$ is increasing and integer-valued.

Let us also show that $X$ has no jumps of size more than one: with probability one, for all $x > 0$, $X(x^-) := \lim_{y \uparrow x} X(y) \geq X(x)-1$. If this failed to hold then there would be $\epsilon > 0$ and $t < \infty$ so that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\exists x \in [0,t), X(x)-X(x^-) \geq 2) > \epsilon/2.
$$
But since $X$ is increasing, for any positive integer $n$ we can bound this probability from above by 
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i < 2n} \mathbb{P}(X((i+1)t/2n)-X((i-1)t/2n) \geq 2)
$$
the point being that these intervals are chosen to overlap so that a jump of size $\geq 2$ must fall in at least one of them. Each of the differences above is distributed as Poisson$(t/n)$, 
so the associated probability is $o(n^{-1})$ as $n \to \infty$ and thus the whole sum tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.

We then know that a process $X$ such as you describe must be increasing and integer valued, with all jumps of size $1$. In other words, $X$ is a point process on $[0,\infty)$. Now the answer from the other thread implies that $X$ must be a rate one Poisson process.

Comment: In our situation, we only know $P(X(A)=0)$ for sets $A$ of the form $A=(s,t]$, which cannot characterize the law of $X$. Hence, the question is still unanswered.

Comment: My last comment is incorrect, but the situation is only more complicated, as the process $X$ is not even known to be a point process (for example, the function $t \mapsto X(t)$ might not be monotone).

Comment: With probability one, for every pair $0 < p < q$, $p,q$ rationals, $X(q)-X(p)$ is a non-negative integer. Since $X$ is cadlag the same property must hold for every real pair $0 < s < t$, i.e. $X$ is increasing and integer-valued, so it is a point process.

Comment: Of course, a trivial mistake of mine. It would have been correct if $X$ was only assumed cadlag with $X(0)=0$ and $X(t) \sim Poi(t)$. However, the question remains unanswered.

Comment: I've elaborated on my answer. If I'm misunderstanding something please let me know. 

Comment: Hi. I think this answer is still wrong. We don't know the probability of there being no jump times in sets which are not intervals. So the result from the other thread on point processes does not apply. In fact, I have a counterexample in mind, which I'll post later.

Comment: My first comment corresponds exactly to George's comment.

Comment: Yes I see now. Sorry for being confused! 

Actually this is already an interesting question in the discrete case. Does there exist a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables with $X_{j+1} + \ldots +X_{j+n}$ having Binomial$(n,1/2)$ distribution for all $j$ and $n$, which is not simply a sequence of independent binomial random variables?

Comment: In the binomial example given above, $X_2 + X_3$ does not have Binomial(2,1/2) distribution (for example, $P(X_2+X_3=0)=1/8$).

Comment: I put in a simpler "example" than the one I initially found but it was too simple. The modified one should work.

Comment: Yes, it works (just note the typo in "$X_3=0$ if ...").